# Copy value from column/row into same table row

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a table `client` that I need to copy the value of one column and paste it to another column in the same row.

Here is the current data:

```
ClientID  Name    DuplicateName
    1     NULL      name1
    2     NULL      name2
    3     NULL      name3
```

I want it to take the data from `duplicateName` and put it into `Name`:

```
ClientID  Name    DuplicateName
    1     name1     name1
    2     name2     name2
    3     name3     name3
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this with a single update statement:

```
update client set Name = DuplicateName
```

This will update every column on the `client` table since there is no where clause and it will set the `Name` column to `DuplicateName`.